# Tenho um BD local em c# sql. Quando fui instalar no cliente deu o seguinte erro

Tags: c#

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Instalei meu projeto no cliente com banco de dados local, levei o bd junto e tal , mas deu esse erro:

[image: Erro projeto login instalado no cliente C#]

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/64574/edit) a pergunta, poste o código e informe a linha onde ocorre o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Isto está acontecendo porque a consulta não está encontrando a tabela `vendedor` no Banco de Dados.

Comment: Adicionalmente, ele deve verificar se executou os scripts no banco de dados para criação dos objetos (tabelas, views, stored procedures).